# How to fix the error Do not fetch data ? in swift and Laravel api

Tags: json, swift, laravel, api

Connected Swift in API built in Laravel but data can not be fetched

I've used it GET and it succeeded and brought the data but when I use POST can not fetch the data

The error that appears in xCode

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Swift code

```
    let session = URLSession.shared

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mydomin.com/index.php/api/profile/1/")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [], options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil, error)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, NSError(domain: "dataNilError", code: -100001, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }

        do {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil, NSError(domain: "invalidJSONTypeError", code: -100009, userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            completion(json, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Laravel Code:

/myWebSite/routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/profile/{userID}','profile@show');
```

/myWebSite/app/Http/controllers/profile.php

```
public function show($userID){

    $users = new User();

    return $users->find($userID);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem I was writing the link so https://mydomin.com/index.php/api/profile/1/ in Swift Code and you modified it to https://mydomin.com/index.php/api/profile/1 and succeeded

**thank myself**

Comment: choose your answer as answered :D